# Use another object's constructor inside your initializer?

Tags: ruby

Consider this code:

```
  Campus = ImmutableStruct.new(:id, :name, :timezone) do
    def hash; id end
  end

  Merchant = ImmutableStruct.new(:id, :name, :campus) do
    def hash; id end
  end
```

Notice the duplication of the `hash` method.  I want to remove this duplication with a new class `ImmutableStructWithId`.  That new class would allow the above 2 lines to be rewritten as follows:

```
Campus = ImmutableStructWithId.new(:id, :name, :timezone)
Merchant = ImmutableStructWithId.new(:id, :name, :campus)
```

*If* ruby's initializer worked like factory functions (they don't), something like the following is what I'd want:

```
class ImmutableStructWithId
  def initialize(*args)
    ImmutableStruct.new(*args) do
      def hash; id end
    end
  end
end
```

I am aware the above won't work, because initializers don't *return* the object they are creating, they just *initialize* it.  But *if they did* work like factory functions, the above is what I'd want to do.

What is the correct way to achieve the same effect in ruby?

Comment: Also, I don't see any constructor specifics. You just don't want to repeat method definition, no?

Comment: Correct.  Ultimately I want to avoid repeating the hash definition, and just use a specific class that has that baked in.

Comment: Decorators/delegators then.

Comment: so I have to create `ImmutableStruct` as a member, and then delegate everything to it?  That is so nasty... Is there not a better way?

Comment: None that I can think of right now :)

Comment: The "factory function" you are looking for is customarily called `new` in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO this should work for you:

```
require 'immutable-struct'

module ImmutableStructWithId
  def self.new(*args)
    ImmutableStruct.new(*args) do
      def hash; id; end
    end
  end
end

Campus = ImmutableStructWithId.new(:id, :name, :timezone)
campus = Campus.new(id: '1', name: 'foo', timezone: 'UTC')
#=> #<Campus:0x007f8ed581de20 @id="1", @name="foo", @timezone="UTC">
campus.hash
#=> "1"
```

Comment: perfect.  wasn't aware you could re-define `new` like that.  does the above only work with `module` -- ie, is there a reason you didn't use `class` here?

Comment: I used a module, because I knew that I do not want to create an instance of it. In this context you might want to consider another name, perhaps `ImmutableStructWithIdFactory`?

Comment: @Jonah: `new` is just a method like any other method. Why wouldn't you be able to define your own? The one you usually inherit from `Class` just looks like this: `class Class; def new(*args, &block) obj = allocate; obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block); obj end end`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i just stupidly assumed it was special for no good reason

Comment: @Jonah: Ruby is exactly a poster child of simplicity, regularity and orthogonality, that is certainly true. But in this case, it is much simpler than it is usually made out to be: there is exactly one kind of methods, namely instance methods. There are no class methods, no static methods, no constructors, no initializers, no functions, no procedures. Unlike e.g. Java, which has three different kinds of "methods" (instance methods, static methods, constructors), Ruby has only one. And they are always dynamically dispatched, always virtual, always overridable (and also always re-definable).

Comment: There are exactly 4 kinds of executable code in Ruby: blocks, methods, class/module definitions, and scripts. (Incidentally, those are also all the lexical scopes there are in Ruby.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks.  your posts always provide new clarity for me